# Why reduce(operator.__not__, [True]) get True?

Tags: python-3.x

```py
reduce(operator.__not__, [False]) # False
reduce(oeprator.__not__, [True]) # True
```

I wrote a solution for [leetocde 1106](https://leetcode.com/problems/parsing-a-boolean-expression/).
Split expressions into groups separated by top level ','; for each top-level sub expression (substrings with braces), process it and add it to the corresponding group; finally combine the groups.

```py
import operator, functools
class Solution:
    def parseBoolExpr(self, expression: str, op=None) -> bool:
        groups = []
        level = 0

        for i, c in enumerate(expression):
            if c == '(':
                if level == 0:
                    start = i + 1
                level += 1
            elif c == ')':
                level -= 1
                if level == 0:
                    groups.append(self.parseBoolExpr(expression[start:i], op))
            elif c == '&':
                op = operator.__and__
            elif c == '|':
                op = operator.__or__
            elif c == '!':
                op = operator.__not__
            elif level == 0:
                if c == 't':
                    groups.append(True)
                else:
                    groups.append(False)

        return functools.reduce(op, groups)
```

but is not work for `operator.__not__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `reduce` takes a function that accepts 2 arguments, the case where the sequence has 1 element is considered an edge-case in which that single element is returned (unless `initial` argument is passed).

```
print(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (x, y), [1]))
# 1
print(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: (x, y), [1], 'with an initial argument'))
# ('with an initial argument', 1)
```

This behavior is documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

> If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the sequence is empty. **If initializer is not given and sequence contains only one item, the first item is returned.**